# $E(G)$ is contractible

Tags: algebraic-topology

On page 128 of [this book](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf), it will constrict the Eilenberg-MacLane spaces $K(\pi, n)$ associated to discrete Abelian groups $\pi$. From this construction, I would like to deduce the following property:

> $\pi_q(K(\pi, n))=0$ if $q\neq n$, and $\pi_q(K(\pi, n))=\pi$ if $q=n$.

To do this, it suffices to say that the space $E(G)$ is contractible. But I cannot do it at all. Could you tell me how to do it or introduce some apposite papers?

Comment: Hint: try to find an extra degeneracy for the simplicial object $E_* G$.  Warning: Skimming that page, I found some of the indexing in the formulas a little peculiar, so be careful!

Comment: Sorry, I cannot make heads or tails of it. What is your attempt? Why should I find it?

Comment: A simplicial object equipped with an extra degeneracy is contractible.  As for how to find it, well, you have $n$ degeneracies $G^n \to G^{n+1}$ that insert the identity element in $n$ of the $n + 1$ spots, so what could an extra degeneracy be?

Comment: I understood your attempt. I knew that an extra degeneracy implies the contractible, for the first time. So I had been trying to prove it, but I cannot do it. Could you give me more advice?

Comment: It seems what you want is Lemma III.5.1 in Goerss-Jardine.  Incidentally, the very next example after the lemma is using it to show that $EG$ is contractible.